# Sharepoint site stopped working. Database "needs upgrading". Upgrade fails

Tags: 2010, upgrade, database

One of my Sharepoint 2010 Site Collections has stopped functioning this morning and presents the following in the browser.

> Server error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=177673

When I look at the "Manage Databases Upgrade Status" for the content database in Central Administration, it tells me

> Database is too old and upgrade is required

Other content databases are fine and the other site collections work.

After Googling, several sites have suggested to run:

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force
```

But this also fails on task 2 of 4 saying

> An exception of type Microsoft.Sharepoint.Administration.SPUpdatedConcurrencyException was thrown. Additional exception information: An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The object SPUpgradeSession Name=Upgrade-20130307-113655-410 was updated by MYDOMAIN\Administrator, in the PSCONFIG (7228) process, on machine MYSERVER.

I am running out of options, short of doing a restore from backup which isn't the preferred solution as this is our company intranet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following to fix the last error and then do the psconfig command again:

> 1.stsadm -o setproperty -pn command-line-upgrade-running -pv No
>
> 2.IISReset
>
> 3.Restart the Windows SharePoint Timer
>
> 4.psconfig –cmd upgrade –inplace b2b –wait –force

http://www.sharepointgeoff.com/spupdatedconcurrencyexception-fix-when-trying-to-install-june-2011-cu-for-sharepoint-server/